# How to implement these ios indicators in android

Tags: android

[image]

How can I implement the 4 circles at the bottom indicating what pages you are on in android?

Is it just a radio group?

Comment: if you are using viewpager then you can use viewpagerindicator liberary for getting those circles at bottom of page.

Comment: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: You should try to implement it first, and then come back here if you face any trouble (but the link given by @Philipp should suit to your request). By the way, `iOS` tag is not necessary here, you are searching how to implement page control in android and you use a picture from iPhone screen, but it could also be from many other system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to implement them inside your **Android** application?

Have a look at the `ViewPagerIndicator` **library**: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

It's exactly what you are looking for.